# Multiple CResourceUsers using a single CResource

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows, static

- I need multiple `CResourceUsers` to share one instance of `CResource`.
- I want to instantiate the `CResource` only if at least one `CResourceUser` exists.
- `CResource` is not singleton by design, there may exist other users of `CResource`
- C++98 is used
- Windows only solution
- `CResource` methods are thread-safe

I started with simple

```
CResource & CResourceUser::Resource() const
{
    static CResource resource("resource");
    return resource;
}
```

Which is supposed to be used like this:

```
CResourceUser::CResourceUser()
{
    std::cout << "+++ CResourceUser" << std::endl;
    Resource().DoSomething();
}
```

But that seems [not to be thred-safe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040308-00/?p=40363).

So I came with a bit complicated solution:

`Synchronisation.h`:

```
#include <Windows.h>

namespace Synchronization {

class CriticalSection 
{ 
    friend class Lock; 

    public: CriticalSection () 
    { 
        ::InitializeCriticalSection (&_critSect); 
    } 

    ~CriticalSection () 
    { 
        ::DeleteCriticalSection (&_critSect);
    } 

    private: CRITICAL_SECTION _critSect; 
};


class Lock 
{ 
    public: Lock (CriticalSection & critSect) : _section (critSect) 
    { 
        ::EnterCriticalSection (&_section._critSect); 
    } 

    ~Lock () 
    { 
        ::LeaveCriticalSection (&_section._critSect); 
    } 

    private: CriticalSection & _section; 
};

}

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
```

The rest of the code now looks a bit better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Synchronization.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CResource
{
public:
    CResource(const std::string &_name)
        :name(_name)
    {
    }

    ~CResource()
    {
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        std::cout << "Something!" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const std::string name;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CResourceUser
{
public:
    CResourceUser()
    {
        Resource().DoSomething();
    }
private:
    CResource & Resource() const
    {
        Synchronization::Lock resourceInitGuard(s_csResourceInit);
        static CResource resource("resource");
        return resource;
    }
    static Synchronization::CriticalSection s_csResourceInit;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Synchronization::CriticalSection CResourceUser::s_csResourceInit;

int main()
{
    CResourceUser user1;
    CResourceUser user2;
    CResourceUser user3;
    return 0;
}
```

So for now I'm OK with the code, it is more readable than the previous revision and it seems to work as expected.

The main question remains: **Is the code correct?**

Please ignore the hungarian notation.